# 2 different names in Microsoft Active Directory

Tags: active-directory

Can you tell me, how I can keep a name in 2 different languages in Microsoft Active Directory?

One name must be in native language (Russian or Chinese), second in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what do you want to use that secondary user name for, you can store it in custom user attribute. This article will help you add it:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/da4761b8-e893-4f35-8a61-bfbc8355e817/active-directory-how-to-add-additional-attributes-to-the-user-objects-in-active-directory?forum=winserverDS

But BE VERY CAREFUL following instructions from this article. Really, you can easily break your whole AD structure, if you don't follow it exactly.

Now, when you have custom attribute, you have to integrate it with target systems, eg. webmail or something else. You didn't write anything about these target systems, so here you have example manual for MediaWiki:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:LDAP_Authentication/Configuration_Options